# Fail installing Office2016 on fresh install Windows10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

This is my Thinkpad Laptop :

```
Device name ThinkPad
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz   2.00 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.89 GB usable)
Device ID   
Product ID  
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   Touch support with 2 touch points
```

Windows describtion:

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎24/‎11/‎2021
OS build    19042.1348
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
```

When I try to install a local copy (saved locally on NAS) I get this error (even though I have all defender and firewall protections down).

What may be the problem ?

[image: snip]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Microsoft Office Live site and log in.

Do three things:

(Make sure in Programs and Features that there is not an existing installation).

1. Install from the Live site. That works great.
2. Check the number of installs you have on your account. Five "computer" installs and 5 more "phone" installs.
3. See if your ThinkPad preload installed Office during the install. If so, it just may need activating.

Also, if Office was preinstalled (selected during your ThinkPad installation) it will most likely conflict with your NAS offline file.

This should help you.